# RunPE memory malfunction

Tags: c++, winapi, portable-executable

Whenever executing my executable file, it works 80% of the time. The other 20% of the time, I receive a 0xc00000005 error from Windows. I believe this may be a memory problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I have spent too much time trying to figure out how I can fix this, so I am now coming here. I'm using Visual Studio.

I debugged the program and it's failing right here at the debug script named "Write process memory step 1: Failed."

```
if (WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL))
{
    for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++)
    {
        SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));

        WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
            LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
    }
```

RunPE function:

```
     /*             PE Execution Function               */
int RunPortableExecutable(void* Image)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* DOSHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* NtHeader;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* SectionHeader;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    STARTUPINFOA SI;

    DWORD* ImageBase;
    void* pImageBase;

    int count;
    char CurrentFilePath[1024];

    DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image);
    NtHeader = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew);

    GetModuleFileNameA(0, CurrentFilePath, 1024);
    if (NtHeader->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        ZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));
        ZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));

        if (CreateProcessA(CurrentFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
            CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI))
        {
            LPCONTEXT CTX = LPCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
            CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;

            if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX)))
            {
                if (ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&ImageBase), 4, 0))
                {
                    pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                    NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                    if (WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL))
                    {
                        for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++)
                        {
                            SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));

                            if (WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
                                LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0))
                            {
                                cout << "Write process memory in FOR statement. Success";
                            }
                            else cout << "Write process memory in FOR statement. Failed";
                        }

                        if (WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8),
                            LPVOID(&NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, 0))
                        {

                            CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + NtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                            if (SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX)))
                            {
                                if (ResumeThread(PI.hThread))
                                {
                                cout << "Resume thread: Success";
                                }
                                else cout << "Resume thread: Failed";
                            }
                            else cout << "Set thread context: Failed";

                        }
                        else cout << "Write process memory step 2: Failed";
                    }
                    else cout << "Write process memory step 1: Failed";
                }
                else cout << "Read process memory: Failed";
            }
            else cout << "Get thread context: Failed";
        }
        else cout << "Create process: Failed";
    }
    else cout << "Get module file name: Failed";
    return 0;
}
```

Warnings messages:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'CTX'.
>   Line 39
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   C6387   'CTX' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'GetThreadContext'. See line 39 for an earlier location where this can occur
>   Line 41
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   C6387   'pImageBase' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'WriteProcessMemory'.
>   Line 48
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   C6387   'CTX' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'SetThreadContext'. See line 39 for an earlier location where this can occur
>   Line 62

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you may wish to see what setting `btInheritHandles` to `TRUE` does for you in `CreateProcessA`

Comment: Just tried that, and sadly it didn't work. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Do you know which line causes Windows to raise the exception?

Comment: Are you compiling this with all warnings enabled? Do you get any warnings on any of the casts?

Comment: No I don't know which line causes Windows to raise the exception. I will start making message boxes and debugging the program to find out which line. And do I receive warnings? Yes I do, mainly for CTX pointer. I will update the post with the warning messages now. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Either run this in a debugger or attach an IDE to the crashed process (the 'Debug' button on the crash popup) and it should show you which line without having to add trace.

Comment: OK, those warnings are probably fine (assuming the VirtualAlloc cannot fail): I was more interested in pointer arithmetic or cast warnings.

Comment: Alright so I debugged the program. It's failed on this line:
if (WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL))
     {
      for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++)
      {
       SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));

       WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
        LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
      }

I put the code in post.

Comment: Please provide the full error diagnostic you get. A 0xC0000005 exception comes with information about the operation attempted to perform, as well as the address.

Comment: It may be caused by `sizeof(CTX)` which should be `sizeof(CONTEXT)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the Randomized Base Address to No in the Linker/Advanced options tab.

Then I added the NtUnmapViewofSection to my code

```
*(DWORD_PTR*)&pNtUnmapViewOfSection = (DWORD_PTR)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"NTDLL.dll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection");
```

Comment: Hi, don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it. [How to mark?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on the calculation of your `NtHeader` pointer and this causes a `denied access` when you try to access to `NtHeader->Signature`. Your pointer should be calculated like this:

```
NtHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)DOSHeader + DOSHeader->e_lfanew);
```

Comment: What's the difference? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: He must use `DOSHeader` calculated in precedent inscruction `DOSHeader = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(Image);` we must not use the `Image` pointer directly, that's why we calculate the header whith `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` ...

Comment: But that's just Image recast to a pointer type, so the actual calculation = Image or DOSHeader + DOSHeader->e_lfanew should be the same shouldn't it? I suppose it might make a difference if DWORD here is too small to store a pointer, i.e. you might need to use DWORD_PTR instead of DWORD, but I'd expect compiler warnings for that.

Comment: "we must not use the Image pointer directly" - why not? PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER isn't a function, it's a typedef i.e. it's used here as a cast.

Comment: @Landstalker, this didn't work. Thanks for trying though. Same problem persists. I am going to start making debug message boxes now for debugging. Until I finish, all posts are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Rup it a cast yes. I meant that we should not use `Image` because it is not typed (void *). we must therefore be vigilant in the cast, especially in the case of a point shift as is the case here. I didn't mean that the two pointers are different in terms of content

Comment: @slicid can you show how you get your `void* Image`

Comment: I get my void* Image from the main function in the code. The main function grabs the block and size of data of testing program. Then I use the argument of data into RunPortableExecutable function.
I think it's grabbing the image correctly or else it wouldn't run 100% of the time. It runs 80% of the time then the other 20% I receive an error.

Comment: I debugged the program and I posted the debug results at the end of the original post.

if (WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, NtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL))
     {
      for (count = 0; count < NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; count++)
      {
       SectionHeader = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(Image) + DOSHeader->e_lfanew + 248 + (count * 40));

       WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + SectionHeader->VirtualAddress),
        LPVOID(DWORD(Image) + SectionHeader->PointerToRawData), SectionHeader->SizeOfRawData, 0);
      }